# Re-adding constraint after ALTER fails on row that exists

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I'm getting a failure trying to add a constraint that previously existed on a table after having dropped it to do an alter:

```
mcqueen=# ALTER TABLE ONLY public.mcqueen_base_imagemeta2
mcqueen-#     ADD CONSTRAINT mcqueen_base_imageme_image_id_616fe89c_fk_mcqueen_b FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES public.mcqueen_base_image(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ERROR:  insert or update on table "mcqueen_base_imagemeta2" violates foreign key constraint "mcqueen_base_imageme_image_id_616fe89c_fk_mcqueen_b"
DETAIL:  Key (image_id)=(5648463223) is not present in table "mcqueen_base_image".
```

I can select that image_id in the both referenced tables and the rows do exist.

I tried changing the PK on the row in mcqueen_base_image to a difference one and back and even deleting and re-adding the row, but neither worked. I finally deleted the row, but then failed on another. Since this table has some 7 billion rows, waiting 2 hours for each failure and deleting that row is not a workable solution.

Is there anything I can do to "repair" this issue?

*UPDATE:* The root issue ended up being some corruption in our backup restore process, so the test DB was just plain corrupt, so no re-indexing or even reloading of tables helped the issue.

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version? `select version();` will show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get that message although the `image_id` is present in `mcqueen_base_image`, you must be dealing with data corruption.

Try to

```
REINDEX mcqueen_base_image;
```

and see if the problem persists.

If there are still problems, you'll have to repair the data manually. Then

- dump and restore the database to a new cluster to get rid of any lingering data corruption.
- investigate the cause of the corruption.

Comment: Tried re-index, dropping and re-creating the PK constraint, but without success. I am now dumping and reloading the table. Fingers crossed

Comment: Restore may fail to create the constraint. Then fix the data manually until it works.

Comment: Restore is how I got here. As in, this is a restored copy of the DB I was testing my alter on and encountered the problem. What I'm doing now is actually a COPY TO; TRUNCATE; COPY FROM